# Do Entity Framework Provide Utility that convert DB Type To C# Type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, types, entity-framework-5

i m building a dynamic class using reflection and type builder and all , i want to know how can i do direct type casting to c# type

currently this way i m doing , but does this kind of thing provided by EF ?

```
 case "uniqueidentifier":
                return typeof(Guid);
            case "bit":
                return typeof(Boolean);
            case "nvarchar":
                return (typeof(string));
            case "datetime":
                return typeof(DateTime);
            case "float":
                return typeof(double);
            case "int":
                return (typeof(int));
```

thanks

**UPDATE**
i assume there is no utility provided by EF till now which is publicly accessible.the answer accepted has nothing to do with Ef. rather different library there.

Ryszard Dżegan has given answer but it can not be used outside TT templates or edmx (or may be i didn't know)

Comment: Have you considered using a `Dictionary<string, Type>` instead of a switch statement?

Comment: ys but i want to use some inner provider from ef which does the thing.. i don't want this switch and cases...

Comment: Well I don't know of anything within EF, but I would definitely say that a dictionary would be cleaner than switch/case.

Comment: thats' true but in a way i don't want to use this approach...as there are so many types there in database..

Comment: I can understand why you wouldn't want to if EF *does* provide something for this, but given the lack of answers it's not clear that anything is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know such a public method (I think there is none... it that may be accepted as answer)

However, try to uncompile sqlmetal.exe, you can have a good idea of how default associations are implemented internally:

In class LinqToSqlShared.Utility.DbTypeSystem (internal class) you can find the method:

```
internal static Type GetClosestRuntimeType(SqlDbType sqlDbType)
{
switch (sqlDbType)
{
    case SqlDbType.BigInt:
        return typeof(long);

    case SqlDbType.Binary:
    case SqlDbType.Image:
    case SqlDbType.Timestamp:
    case SqlDbType.VarBinary:
        return typeof(Binary);

    case SqlDbType.Bit:
        return typeof(bool);

    case SqlDbType.Char:
    case SqlDbType.NChar:
    case SqlDbType.NText:
    case SqlDbType.NVarChar:
    case SqlDbType.Text:
    case SqlDbType.VarChar:
        return typeof(string);

    case SqlDbType.DateTime:
    case SqlDbType.SmallDateTime:
    case SqlDbType.Date:
    case SqlDbType.DateTime2:
        return typeof(DateTime);

    case SqlDbType.Decimal:
    case SqlDbType.Money:
    case SqlDbType.SmallMoney:
        return typeof(decimal);

    case SqlDbType.Float:
        return typeof(double);

    case SqlDbType.Int:
        return typeof(int);

    case SqlDbType.Real:
        return typeof(float);

    case SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier:
        return typeof(Guid);

    case SqlDbType.SmallInt:
        return typeof(short);

    case SqlDbType.TinyInt:
        return typeof(byte);

    case SqlDbType.Xml:
        return typeof(XElement);

    case SqlDbType.Time:
        return typeof(TimeSpan);

    case SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset:
        return typeof(DateTimeOffset);
}
return typeof(object);
}
```

**edit**:

- See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx) as a reference
- There is also a method `static SqlDbType Parse(string stype)` in the same class which returns an enum SqlDbType from sql type string definition.

Comment: thanks for pointing me out to sqlmetal , but my point is that i have string representation of database type from information_schema table like nvarchar,bit,varchar etc..this method accepts sqldbtype as an argument which i don't know.. there's must be something in EF which does that nicely , i need to decompile that..

Comment: I mentioned the function which converts string db type to SqlDbType enum as well. I can include it in answer if you wish :)

Answer (score 2):

I can assume that since Entity Framework is capable of creating Mappings between Conceptual Model and Storage Model, it has internal ability to cast each database type to corresponding conceptual type.

Moreover, Entity Framework uses auxiliary classes that exist in EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude header in its T4 templates to generate context and entities source files.

EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude in turn internally uses classes from [System.Data.Metadata.Edm Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in particular [PrimitiveTypeKind Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.primitivetypekind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which covers conceptual types and constitutes bridge between database types and CLR types.

Value of [PrimitiveTypeKind Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.primitivetypekind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be found as property in [PrimitiveType Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.primitivetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and that class has another interesting property called [ClrEquivalentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.primitivetype.clrequivalenttype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which as expected returns [System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[PrimitiveType Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.primitivetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instances can be fetched in various ways. In T4 templates Entity Framework works with [EdmItemCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.edmitemcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has [GetPrimitiveTypes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351416%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In T4 templates, the simplest way to access [EdmItemCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.edmitemcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is to use MetadataLoader's (from EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude) CreateEdmItemCollection method which takes as parameter path to edmx file.

In tt file, you could write:

```
<#@ template hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude" #><#

var edmxPath = "NorthwindModel.edmx"; // <--- Put the path to your model here.
var loader = new MetadataLoader(this);
var edmItemCollection = loader.CreateEdmItemCollection(edmxPath);
var primitiveTypes = edmItemCollection.GetPrimitiveTypes();

#>
<#
foreach (var primitiveType in primitiveTypes)
{
#>
<#= primitiveType#> ==> <#= primitiveType.ClrEquivalentType#>
<#
}
#>
```

The result will be:

```
Edm.Binary ==> System.Byte[]
Edm.Boolean ==> System.Boolean
Edm.Byte ==> System.Byte
Edm.DateTime ==> System.DateTime
Edm.Decimal ==> System.Decimal
Edm.Double ==> System.Double
Edm.Guid ==> System.Guid
Edm.Single ==> System.Single
Edm.SByte ==> System.SByte
Edm.Int16 ==> System.Int16
Edm.Int32 ==> System.Int32
Edm.Int64 ==> System.Int64
Edm.String ==> System.String
Edm.Time ==> System.TimeSpan
Edm.DateTimeOffset ==> System.DateTimeOffset
Edm.Geometry ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry
Edm.Geography ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography
Edm.GeometryPoint ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry
Edm.GeometryLineString ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry
Edm.GeometryPolygon ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry
Edm.GeometryMultiPoint ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry
Edm.GeometryMultiLineString ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry
Edm.GeometryMultiPolygon ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry
Edm.GeometryCollection ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry
Edm.GeographyPoint ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography
Edm.GeographyLineString ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography
Edm.GeographyPolygon ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography
Edm.GeographyMultiPoint ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography
Edm.GeographyMultiLineString ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography
Edm.GeographyMultiPolygon ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography
Edm.GeographyCollection ==> System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography
```

In plain C# code, you could do same thing if you would have MetadataLoader. To omit this obstacle, you can just copy the MetadataLoader class into your code. However there are also other ways to achieve the goal. If you work with Code First approach, the interesting solution is to use [EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx Method (DbContext, XmlWriter)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696608%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in order to create edmx file dynamicly in [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then put that stream as argument into [XmlReader.Create Method (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756wd7zs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and finally use xml reader as input parameter in [EdmItemCollection Constructor (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There are also methods to replace CLR types by C# types (Nullable<System.Int32> ==> int?) but it is a different story...

Comment: If you have edmx file, your job will be easier then :) If not, you can generate it into memory stream as I've shown you.